# AR(1) model - which prior to use?

Tags: bayesian, arima, prior, jags, uninformative-prior

I want to use the following *univariate* model:

$y_t = \mu_t + \epsilon_t, \ \epsilon_t \sim N(0,1)$

$\mu_t = \phi \mu_{t-1} + \omega_t, \ \omega_t \sim N(0,\sigma_\omega^2)$

That is, $\mu_t$ follows an AR(1) process. I need a prior for $\phi$, however I **don't** want to impose stationarity conditions.

What is a suitable (uninformative/weakly informative) prior (preferably also: what is the code for it in Bugs/Jags)?

I was thinking it might make sense to have $\phi \propto \phi^{-1}$, but I haven't been able find anything in the literature yet.

If someone could provide a reference that would be great (but answers without references are also more than welcome)!

Comment: Do you want to allow for the possibility that $\phi$ might be negative?  If so, you'll need to adapt your suggested prior.

Comment: @rbm,  a standard approach is you do not want (or have) stationary data is to work with differences e.g. $d_t=y_t-y_{t-1}$ and determine if the $d_t$ are stationary, if not again take differences of differences (usually not more than 2 differences are required), will this difference approach not work to achieve a stationary series in your case?